# Socket JAVA no local

Tags: java, socket

Tengo una aplicacion donde abro un socket;

```
server = new ServerSocket(25000, 1, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
```

Y un cliente que se conecta a el;

```
private Socket socket;
this.socket = new Socket("localhost", 25000);
```

El programa funciona perfectamente en local, mi pregunta es, como podria hacer para comunicar el programa en diferentes ordenadores ¿Tego que pasarle al cliente la direccion IP del servidor si o si, o existe alguna manera que lo pueda hacer de manera automatica?

El objetivo seria no hacerle introducir al usuario la direccion IP del servidor, ya que no es practico ni facil para el Usuario.

Comment: Si no la IP, al menos debería conocer su "nombre" (lo que supone que el servidor tiene un nombre de dominio y una entrada correctamente configurada en el DNS). Por cierto, que en el servidor no necesitas especificar su IP para crear el socket. Puedes usar la ip "0.0.0.0" que representa "cualquiera de las IPs que tiene esta máquina".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has dado muchos detalles sobre cómo está montado tu proyecto, pero en definitiva necesitas que el programa cliente conozca la IP de tu servidor de antemano: Mientras estás haciendo el desarrollo/pruebas, puedes usar `localhost` o la IP real de tu máquina, pero si ese programa llega a tener un uso real:

- Si el servidor tiene una IP fija, puedes ponerla con una constante en el programa cliente.
- Si el servidor va a estar en una red de una empresa o con una IP pública en Internet, es posible que la IP la puedas asociar a un dominio mediante un DNS.

Otras soluciones más complejas serían que el cliente se conectara a otro servidor con la IP fija y obtuviera la IP de tu servidor.

Comment: Vale gracias, no era dudas a nivel de la aplicación simplemente quería saber que formas podía emplear para no tener que introducir la IP a mano.